# Trying to format a SSD but get "no available data" error

Tags: partitioning, ssd, disk-formatting

My Windows 11 system blue screened yesterday and I shut it down because it stucked at 0%. After that Windows cannot boot and shows 0xc0000f error code, which basically means the boot manager cannot locate BCD (Boot Configuration Database). After trying many solutions but failed, I decided to copy the important data from that SSD and format it in Ubuntu system instead.

Then here comes the issue: When I use `mkfs` to format the disk, it gives input/output error, and then the SSD cannot be found neither in *Disks* nor `fdisk` nor BIOS. The only way to get it back is completely shutting down and restart. When I open `gparted` it keeps showing "no data available" and "Retry" and "Ignore" options like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4GeG.png). After clicking many times of "Ignore", `gparted` shows the SSD like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4uU6.png). And when I create partition table or format it, the "no data available" error shows again and again. The information of the SSD shown in *Disks* is shown as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDcs6.png). It has no partition table, no file system, nothing.

Is there any means to completely reinitialize the SSD in Ubuntu?